# A series related to Catalan numbers

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory, hypergeometric-function, catalan-numbers

Recall the definition of [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number):
$$C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n=\frac{2^n(2n-1)!!}{(n+1)!}.\tag1$$
Now consider the following series with a parameter $n\in\mathbb N^+$:
$$S_n=\frac{2\cdot18^n}{3\sqrt5}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{C_{2k}\cdot k^n}{5^{2k}}.\tag2$$
It appears that $S_n$ is always integer (and odd), with the following values for $n=1,2,3,...:$
$$1, 43, 3009, 318507, 46065921, 8482079403, 1899432317889, 501282878789547,...$$
([click here](http://gist.githubusercontent.com/VladimirReshetnikov/08b7a12673df44a07bae/raw/26083eb2ed5b36f9c5bc82d6561265b082d052ba/gistfile1.txt) to see more terms)

---

Can we prove that $S_n$ is always integer (odd)? Can we find an explicit formula for $S_n$ not involving an infinite summation?

Comment: Did you try entering the first terms in your sequence at o.e.i.s. ? If lucky it may already be there...

Comment: Yes, I tried OEIS and OEIS "superseeker" -- they did not find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{2 k+1} \binom{4 k}{2 k} x^k $$

Then differentiating, multiplying, integrating, etc., we find that

$$f(x) = \frac1{4 \sqrt{x}} \left [(1+4 \sqrt{x})^{1/2} - (1-4 \sqrt{x})^{1/2} \right ] - 1$$

It should be plain that, if we define the operator

$$\mathcal{D} = x \frac{d}{dx} $$

Then

$$S_n = \frac{2 \cdot 18^n}{3 \sqrt{5}} \mathcal{D}^n f\left (\frac1{25} \right ) $$

Comment: Thanks! This solves the explicit formula problem. Can we infer from here that it is always an integer?

Comment: Maple says this is: $$\frac{2}{3}\frac{18^n}{\sqrt{5}} \sum_{q=1}^n {n\brace q}  \left(\frac{d}{dz}\right)^q \left. \frac{5\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{25+5\sqrt{9-16z}}} \right|_{z=0}.$$

Comment: This can be re-written to yield $$ \frac{2}{3}\frac{n!\times 18^n}{\sqrt{5}} 
[z^n] \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-16\exp(z)/25}}}.$$